# Как передать переменную из другого приложения через URL в view

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

```
Возможно ли передать переменную из другого приложения через URL в view
**APP_config/models**

    class DirectoryBase(models.Model):
        """Абстрактная модель для справочников"""
        class Meta:
            abstract = True
        comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, db_column="comment", verbose_name="Comment")
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column="is_active", verbose_name="Is active")
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)


    class Employee(DirectoryBase):
        """Имя сотрудника, например Хулев И.И."""
        employee = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_column="employee", verbose_name="Employee")

        class Meta():
            db_table = 'Employee'
            ordering = ['employee']
            verbose_name = 'Employee'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Employees'

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s" % self.employee


    class Line(DirectoryBase):
        """Производственная линия"""
        line = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_column="line", verbose_name="Line")

        class Meta():
            db_table = 'Line'
            ordering = ['line']
            verbose_name = 'Line'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Lines'

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s" % self.line
**APP_department/models**

    class DeptBase(models.Model):
        """Абстрактная модель для производственных участков"""
        class Meta:
            abstract = True
        comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, db_column="comment", verbose_name="Comment")
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column="is_active", verbose_name="Is active")
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)


    class CoolingDept(DeptBase):
        """Coolling department"""
        line = models.OneToOneField("APP_config.Line")
        foreman_name = models.ForeignKey("APP_config.Employee", related_name="foreman_name")
        soldering_comp_name = models.ForeignKey("APP_config.Employee", related_name="soldering_comp_name")

        class Meta():
            db_table = 'CoolingDept'
            ordering = ['line']
            verbose_name = 'CoolingDept'
            verbose_name_plural = 'CoolingDepts'

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s" % self.line

**APP_zebra_print/models**

    class Barcode(models.Model):
        """Печать штрихкодов"""
        barcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="barcode", verbose_name="Barcode")
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

        class Meta():
            db_table = 'Barcode'
            ordering = ['created']
            verbose_name = 'Barcode'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Barcodes'

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s" % self.barcode

**APP_zebra_print/urls**

    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
    from .views import barcode_add_coolingdept1


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^zebra_print/barcode_add/coolingdept/1/$', views.barcode_add_coolingdept1,
        name='barcode_add_coolingdept1'),
        # url(r'^zebra_print/barcode_add/coolingdept/(?P<line_id>\d+)/$', views.barcode_add_coolingdept1, name='barcode_add_coolingdept1'),
    ]

**APP_zebra_print/views**
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    from APP_department.models import CoolingDept
    from .forms import BarcodeCoolingDept1Form

    from datetime import datetime


    def barcode_add_coolingdept1(request, error_barcode=""):
    #def barcode_add_coolingdept1(request, line_id, error_barcode=""):
        """Добавляем новый штрихкод. Результат ошибки error_barcode будет использоваться в шаблоне"""
        if request.method != 'POST':
            # Данные не отправлялись; создается пустая форма.
            form_barcode = BarcodeCoolingDept1Form()
            print("GET")
        else:
            print("POST")
            # Отправлены данные POST; обработать данные.
            form_barcode = BarcodeCoolingDept1Form(request.POST)
            print("request")
            print(request.POST)
            if form_barcode.is_valid():
                print("is_valid")
                form_barcode = form_barcode.save(commit=False)
                line_id = 2
                coolingdept = CoolingDept.objects.get(id=line_id)
                line = coolingdept.line
                foreman_name = coolingdept.foreman_name
                soldering_comp_name = coolingdept.soldering_comp_name
                date_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
                print(line)
                print(foreman_name)
                print(soldering_comp_name)
                print(date_time)
                form_barcode.save()
                print("save")
                print(form_barcode)
                # Мы используем вызов reverse() для получения URL-адреса страницы topics и передаем его
                # функции HttpResponseRedirect(), перенаправляющей браузер пользователя на страницу topics.
                # На этой странице пользователь видит только что введенную им тему в общем списке тем.
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('APP_zebra_print:barcode_add_coolingdept1'))

        context = {'form': form_barcode, 'error_barcode': error_barcode}
        return render(request, 'APP_zebra_print/barcode_add.html', context)

Хочется передавать переменную line_id (APP_department.CoolingDept) через 

    url(r'^zebra_print/barcode_add/coolingdept/(?P<line_id>\d+)/$', views.barcode_add_coolingdept1, name='barcode_add_coolingdept1'), 
и получить ее в 

    def barcode_add_coolingdept1(request, line_id, error_barcode="")
```